# Partition from partitioned step - Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a scenario where I need to bring in parallelism in two steps, second should spawn multi threads from first which also have number of threads as per partitition.

Archival of history or suspended records for an active record is the scenario - there cab be n suspended for each active.

Currently the same is achieved through step looping with a decider as follows

```
<batch:job id="agreementDataArchiveJob">
        <batch:step id="getActiveRecordStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="getActiveRecordsTask"
                task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            <batch:next on="CONTINUE" to="getSuspendedRecordsStep"></batch:next>
            <batch:end on="COMPLETED" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="getSuspendedRecordsStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="getSuspendedRecordsToArchiveTask"
                task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            <batch:next on="CONTINUE" to="archiveSuspendedDataStep"></batch:next>
            <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="archivalStepDecider"/>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="archiveSuspendedDataStep" next="archivalStepDecider">
            <batch:partition partitioner="archiveSuspendedDataPartitioner"
                handler="suspendedAgreementArchivalPartitionHandler" step="suspendedAgreementArchival">
            </batch:partition>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:decision decider="archivalStepExecutionDecider"
            id="archivalStepDecider">
            <batch:next on="CONTINUE" to="getSuspendedRecordsStep"></batch:next>
            <batch:end on="COMPLETED"></batch:end>
        </batch:decision>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="archivalBatchListener"></batch:listener>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>
```

Here one active is taken, its suspended will be purged in multiple threads- proceed to next active. 
    To optimize performance need to bring parallelism in such a way as processing multiple active records simultaneously should happen - Each active id thread invoking multiple parallel threads to remove its history records

```
<batch:job id="multilevelDataArchiveJob">
        <batch:step id="getActiveRecordStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="getActiveRecordsTask"
                task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            <batch:next on="CONTINUE" to="getActiveIdsForConcurrentExecution"></batch:next>
            <batch:end on="COMPLETED"/> 
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="getActiveIdsForConcurrentExecution" next="processSuspendedIds">
            <batch:partition step="getSuspendedForActiveRecordStep" 
                partitioner="readActiveDataPartitioner" handler="activeRecordPartitionHandler" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="processSuspendedIds" parent="getActiveIdsForConcurrentExecution">
            <batch:partition partitioner="archiveSuspendedDataPartitioner"
                handler="suspendedDataArchivalPartitionHandler" step="suspendedDataArchival" />
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

But this is executing second chunk step for only one active, even though multiple partitions are being created for processing active records

How can we change the configuration to achieve multi-level parallelism?
Do we need to change the approach.